# How can I make use of bricks, rock and miscellaneous fill left in my yard?

Tags: landscaping, backyard, rock

I bought a house last fall and now that spring is here i am cleaning up the yard.  I have been finding alot of bricks, brick sized rocks and brick sized miscellaneous fill (peices asphalt, rock embedded concrete, etc).  Additionally i have typical white garden rocks. i was hoping someone had a way to repurpose them.  I thought about cleaning then up and maybe even painting them, at least the bigger pieces.  Or maybe just breaking them all down with a sledge hammer.  What else could I use possibly use them for?

Comment: Is your main goal to avoid the cost of hauling the random rocks away?

Answer (score 1):

You could create some really cool mosaics.

[Here’s my favorite](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://i.pinimg.com/originals/aa/cc/b2/aaccb2210f9f9471fc37cadb0812f1c6.jpg&imgrefurl=https://www.pinterest.com/pin/63613413459895190/&tbnid=c0JZpc_x9NkQzM&vet=1&docid=1F2Erue2i7E99M&w=800&h=600&hl=en&source=sh/x/im). It’s of Greek women on the island of Sicily (before it was Italian) doing their athletic competitions in bikinis.

They say the bikini was invented in 1950, but this is proof they were around a long time before that.

Comment: Hmm, definitely a beautiful mosaic but how do you know the women are Grecian? I thought Sicily was occupied by North Africans (Carthaginians) prior to Rome taking it...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Hmmm...I think Greece colonized most of the Mediterranean first. Here’s a link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Sicily#Greek_period

Comment: thanks! I love it... especially the ancient bikinis...

Answer (score 0):

I often bury stuff like that.    Often we will break up a slab at a house and why spend all that time and money trying move it around.   Dig a hole 30 feet away and bury it all.  Just make sure it isn't close to structure or electrical lines.

Answer (score 0):

I used the bricks from my house and a few other houses to make an 8' X 12' floor for my garden shed.